# ScalaIDE - a strangeness of a method that ends with colon

Tags: scala, syntax, type-inference

I have come to an idea that in order to create a prefix method for an object, I could use `:` at te end of the method name, hence, I wrote:

```
def aaa: {
}
```

and it compiles just fine! However, this is of no use, so I want to make the method return something, so, uncertain, I write:

```
def aaa: = {
}
```

error!

```
- identifier expected but '=' found.
- not found: type <error>
```

Ok, I understand that the compiler breaks at `: =`, I become curious and I try:

```
def aaa: {
  println("wow")
}
```

error again!

```
illegal start of declaration (possible cause: missing `=' in front of current method body)
```

Then I try this:

```
val a = aaa
```

and it says (hovering over `aaa`) that `aaa` signature is `def aaa: AnyRef`, so I try:

```
def aaa: {
  Global
}
```

where `Global` is an `object`. Still error. So, my question is: why this syntax is allowed? I can't make it work like a prefix method, I can't use this method for side-effects and I can't make it return anything. Why does it allow me to write like this in the first place?

**UPDATE:**

now I try this:

```
def aaa: {} = {
  Global
}
```

and it works. So looks like that `{}` denotes `AnyRef`. Starts feeling like I am in the JavaScript wonderland.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get these error, because a colon at the end of a method name means, that you'd like to specify a return type. If you then don't give one, the compiler complains. With `{}` it works, because you give a type, in this case an empty structural type, which is basically the same as `AnyRef`. There are rules, when you are actually allowed to add a colon at the end of a method name, afaik the method can only consist of non-alphanumeric characters. So `def +:(x:Int)` is ok, `def foo:(x:Int)` leads to an error. But I'm not quiet sure about that. Also methods that end with a colon are right-associative.

Comment: `def foo_: (x: Int)` would be okay. You have to separate alphanumericals and operator symbols in identifiers with `_`.